# Keras custom loss: pool values into histograms

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow backend. I would like to create a new custom loss function where I pool the individual values of y_true and y_pred into bins (think of a histogram), and then calculate the chi2 between the two histograms.

I understand tensor object are not iterable, so I can't loop over the individual elements of y_true and y_pred to fill the histograms.

#### Update:

I tried to create a loss function like this:

```
def Chi2Loss(y_true, y_pred):
     h_true = tf.histogram_fixed_width( y_true, value_range=(-1., 1.), nbins=20) 
     h_pred = tf.histogram_fixed_width( y_true, value_range=(-1., 1.), nbins=20) 
     return K.mean(K.square(h_true - h_pred))
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match
>   type int32 of argument 'x'.

Comment: Hello there. Could you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I tried to create a loss function like this:

def Chi2Loss(y_true, y_pred):

    h_true = tf.histogram_fixed_width(
        y_true, value_range=(-1., 1.), nbins=20)
    h_pred = tf.histogram_fixed_width(
        y_true, value_range=(-1., 1.), nbins=20)

    return K.mean(K.square(h_true - h_pred))

But I get an error:

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.

Comment: Does it help to convert the int32 values of argument 'x' to float32 values?

Comment: if I add the option dtype=tf.float32 I get the following error:
```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'dtype' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of numerical types: `tf.histogram_fixed_width` can just provide a `int32` or `int64` tensor, while `K.square` does not support any of these formats.

Solution: cast the `tf.histogram_fixed_width` output to a compatible numerical type, e.g. `float32`:

```
def Chi2Loss(y_true, y_pred):
    h_true = tf.histogram_fixed_width( y_true, value_range=(-1., 1.), nbins=20)
    h_pred = tf.histogram_fixed_width( y_pred, value_range=(-1., 1.), nbins=20)
    h_true = tf.cast(h_true, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
    h_pred = tf.cast(h_pred, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
    return K.mean(K.square(h_true - h_pred))
```

Comment: Did you try this? Because this shouldn't work. Ints aren't differentiable.

Answer (score -1):

i think it is because `y_pred` or `Y_true` is not directly used in the `return` and keras complains.

you can use this litle trick in keras:

```
def Chi2Loss(y_true, y_pred):
     h_true = tf.histogram_fixed_width( y_true, value_range=(-1., 1.), nbins=20) 
     h_pred = tf.histogram_fixed_width( y_pred, value_range=(-1., 1.), nbins=20) 
     return K.mean(K.square(h_true - h_pred)) + y_pred*0
```

hope it helps